# Lost network connectivity after a "yum -y update"

Tags: networking, yum, lost

I've a server on Centos 6.5 and after a yum -y update we've lost all connectivity on it, the only access we have is on shell thru SolusVM serial console, I've tried everything (SFTP, SCP) on my reach to reestablish the network but doesn't seem to run, and we can't get out our backups to reinstall everything.

Anyone has an idea that could work? i'm really desperate :(

Comment: what does `ip addr`, `ip link` and `ip route` look like?

Comment: `[root@server NetworkManager]# ip addr 
bash: ip: command not found
[root@server NetworkManager]# ip link
bash: ip: command not found
[root@server NetworkManager]# ip route
bash: ip: command not found
[root@server NetworkManager]#`

Comment: I've also noticed that Network or NetworkManager it's not running on my server, I've been reading about it and this might be the answer

Comment: '[root@server init.d]# chkconfig --list
messagebus      0:off 1:off 2:on 3:on 4:on 5:on 6:off
modules_dep     0:off 1:off 2:on 3:on 4:on 5:on 6:off
named           0:off 1:off 2:on 3:on 4:on 5:on 6:off
nscd            0:off 1:off 2:off 3:off 4:off 5:off 6:off
portreserve     0:off 1:off 2:on 3:off 4:on 5:on 6:off
rpcbind         0:off 1:off 2:on 3:off 4:on 5:on 6:off'

Comment: Can you use `ifconfig`? I find it strange that the `ip` command is not found on a Cent 6 box.

Comment: ifconfig just shows nothing, adds another line

Comment: Whelp yep your network stack sounds jacked - out of curiosity did you reboot after running yum update?

Comment: Yes I did because I tho that rebooting would help to get back online, but it didn't...

Comment: I would check `dmesg` and your system logs in `/var/log` to see if there is any idication as to why the nic is missing

Comment: Is there any way we can recover these services without reinstalling -yet- the droplet ? If we reinstall the droplet I know we'll get back online, but we'll lose the data :(

Comment: 1) ask digital ocean to recover the data if they can or 2) Figure out why the nic isn't being seen by looking at your logs.

Comment: We're not on digitalocean and yes, seems that everything got deleted... http://pastebin.com/2wkqGiQi